# PHP echo date as a string

Tags: php, date

How do I `echo` a date as a string such as `07/18`(month/day)?

Comment: This isn't converting the time() function into a string....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php

echo date('m/d');

?>
```

If you already have the timestamp, just use it in the second parameter:

```
<?php

echo date('m/d', time());

?>
```

[demo](http://phpfiddle.io/fiddle/556020331)

Comment: How did you answer this question *after* it was closed as a dupe?

Comment: Awesome thanks! I didn't notice the second parameter

Comment: John, probably because the page was already opened. Not sure. Brandon, np! Happy coding